# Generalized force expression for this "airplane" oscillator system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, vibrations

I am reading a book on aircraft dynamics ([Blakelock *Aircraft and Missiles*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/ubcczZUDCsMC?hl=en&gbpv=0)) where the author presents the following system on page 408:

[image]

Lagrange's equation is given by:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot q_j}\right)-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j}
+\frac{\partial F}{\partial\dot q_j}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_j}=Q_j,~j=1,2,\dots,n,
$$

where $T$ is the kinetic energy, $U$ is the potential energy (including internal strain energy), $F$ is one half the rate at which energy is dissipated, and $Q_j$ is the generalized external force acting on the $j$th station, with $q_j$ representing the $j$th station's generalized coordinate.

In this case, the author splits each force $P_j$ in the above diagram into a gravitational force $P_{g_j}$ and an aerodynamic force $P_{a_j}$. The gravitation force is of course included in the potential energy term, whereas the aerodynamic force is included in $Q_j$. Furthermore, because the system is symmetric, only half of it is considered. With this in mind, the author says that:

$$
Q_0=P_{a_0}+P_{a_1}+P_{a_2},~
Q_1=P_{a_1},~
Q_2=P_{a_2}.
$$

My question is why is the generalized force $Q_0$ equal to the sum of *all* the aerodynamic forces? I don't see how the center station (the airplane fuselage) is different from the other stations. In particular, I would have said that $Q_0=P_{a_0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My question is why is the generalized force Q0 equal to the sum of all the aerodynamic forces?"

if you start with the positions of $p_0~,p_1~,p_2$
you obtain

$$p_0=q_0~,p_1=q_0+q_1~,p_2=q_0+q_2$$

with :

$$\vec{R}=\begin{bmatrix}
   p_0\\
   p_1\\
   p_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

the generalized coordinate vector $\vec{q}$

$$\vec{q}=\begin{bmatrix}
   q_0\\
   q_1\\
   q_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and the applied force vector $\vec{F}$

$$\vec{F}=\begin{bmatrix}
   F_1\\
   F_2\\
   F_3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

you obtain the generalized force vector $\vec{Q}$

$$\vec{Q}=J^T\,\vec{F}$$

where J is the  Jacobi matrix $$J=\frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial \vec q}= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 1&1&0
\\ 1&0&1\end {array} \right] 
$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\vec{Q}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} {F_1}+{ F_2}+{ F_3}
\\  {F_2}\\  {F_3}\end {array}
 \right] ~\surd
$$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. My mistake was to treat the generalized force = applied force.